# How to pass a data from a property in a button modal in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap code below. When the button is clicked, the modal is showing correctly.

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header"> 
    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>&nbsp; New Message</h4>
  </div>      
  <div class="modal-body">
   <!--  data should be displayed here when an href button is clicked -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to pass a data from `a` button tag to be displayed inside the `modal body`. What I need is to append a property inside the `a` tag like `data-content` and when it is clicked, it will be displayed inside the modal-body.

But, i don't know how.

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have jquery in your HTML head. If not add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your HTML should look something like this: (I changed the class of the a element to my-btn. Be free to change it to whatever you like.)

```
<a href="#" class="my-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"
   data-content="hello">Test Btn</a>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>&nbsp; New Message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--  data should be displayed here when an href button is clicked -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your javascript code should look something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.my-btn').click(function () {
        var myDataValue = $(this).data('content');
        $('.modal-body').text(myDataValue);
      })
    });
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

you already has your answer my friend data- tag will do the trick try something like

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-myVal="My sample Value" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header"> 
    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>&nbsp; New Message</h4>
  </div>      
  <div class="modal-body">
   <!--  data should be displayed here when an href button is clicked -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and in script side

```
<script>
$(function()
{
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
$('.modal-body').html($('.btn').data('myVal'));
})
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one dude.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modalButton").click(function(){
      var value = $(this).data("content");
      $("#modal-input").val(value);
      
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                                               <!-- look at the data-value.. -->
<div class="text-center">
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-content="Your Content" id="modalButton">Click here</a>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header"> 
    <h4 class="modal-title">&nbsp; Your Modal</h4>
  </div>      
  <div class="modal-body">
  <input class="form-control" id="modal-input">
   <!--  data should be displayed here when an href button is clicked -->
  </div>
</div>
```